# SPARQL Query view in Protege is not working when an ontology is opened

Tags: sparql, protege

I'm using Protege 5.6.1. The SPARQL view is not working when I have an ontology opened. On the contrary, when there is no ontology opened, the windows is working. How can I solve this issue? For more details please click on the following links to Protege Sparql view screens.

[Before opening an ontology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0x5v.png)

[After opening an ontology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3IPs.png)

Comment: there is a bug if you look at the log file: `Uncaught Exception in thread 'AWT-EventQueue-0' 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.model.AbstractTranslator.<init>(org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager, org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology, boolean, org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.IndividualAppearance, org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.AxiomAppearance, java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger, java.util.Map)'
 at org.protege.owl.rdf.impl.RDFTranslator.<init>(RDFTranslator.java:107) ~[na:na]`

Comment: see https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/issues/1110

Comment: Thank you for help! I have noticed in the GitHub that “ This is a low priority IMO because I almost never use the SPARQL Tab anyway, perhaps it should just be removed”. Why is the that? Is not necessary SPARQL because DL Query in Protege is capable to create queries as complex as those using SPARQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in an upstream-library that is used as a dependency and where the API changed, see https://github.com/protegeproject/rdf-library/issues/12.

I'd assume that someone will shortly fix this. (Maybe subscribe to the issue to give them a little bit of motivation :-).

You can use the `Snap SPARQL plugin` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to Protege 5.5, SPARQL works just fine